# How to use url_for in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm having some trouble using **url_for** in Flask.
I have a template with a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{{ url_for('login', provider='google') }}" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-google fa-lg"></i>  Login with <strong>Google</strong>
</a>
```

Now, when I press the button my URL changes from `http://localhost:5000/login` to `http://localhost:5000/login?provider=google`.

Then my python code:

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

I do not know how to modify my python code so that it can handle this *provider*.

The documentation isn't very clear about this, at least I haven't been able to understand it.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I've tried what seemed obvious with no success:

```
@app.route("/login?provider=<provider>")
def login(provider):
    if provider == 'google':
        return "Hello, Google!"
    return render_template('login.html')
```

But now it wont find `http://localhost:5000/login`, wich is kind of obvious also.

**EDIT 2**:

I managed to make it work, but I don't know if it's a good practice:

```
@app.route("/login")
@app.route("/login?provider=<provider>")
def login(provider = None):
    if provider == 'google':
        return "Hello, Google!"
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I started this today, so maybe I'm wrong. I have this template, given by my teacher. When I press the button I should be able to do something about it, like, printing something, whatever. But I can't find a way to modify my python code so that It can see that I pressed the button.

Comment: So when the button is pressed you just want it to route to a function in python? I don't think you have to use url_for() to do this.

Comment: I don't think the route annotation can contain URL  query parameters

Comment: I really don't know if it's the way to use it. The teacher said I can't modify the template so...

Comment: If you are trying to get the piece after the question mark, try this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24892131/2308683

Comment: That worked! Thanks!