# Flask API Attribute request

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to write a get request for a list of actors using flask.  Here is an example json data object:

```
{
 "age": 61, 
 "json_class": "Actor",  
 "name": "Bruce Willis", 
 "total_gross": 562709189
}
```

How would I write the flask get request such that '/actors?attr={attr_value}' would filter out such that if it was "actors?name='Bruce'", would give me all actors with the name Bruce.

Something along this line I believe:

```
@app.route('/actors? (what here)', methods=['GET'])
def actorByAttr(name):
   names = [data[string] for string in data if data[string]['json_class'] == 'Actor' and string == name]
   if len(names) > 0:
     return jsonify(names[0])
   else:
     return jsonify({'message': "No one found with name: "+ name})
```

EDIT: Also, how could I incorporate AND and OR operators, such as:

```
name=”Bruce”|name=”Matt”, name=”Bruce”&age=61
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask how to get parameters from a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/python-flask-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url)

Comment: what you're asking about is called URL Parameters. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/python-flask-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url for example on how to parse url parameters from a GET request

Comment: @FuzzyAmi Thanks, that go me everything except the OR operator.  When I AND, it parses it fine, but OR gives this: 

          ImmutableMultiDict([('age', u'28|age=61')])
          ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '28|age=61'

Comment: yes, there's a trick here: the "&" *is* part of the URL params spec, but "|" is *not*. and actually, "&" doesn't mean "and" in this context. its means, "the next parameter". when you request with multiple parameters, the "&" delimits one parameter from another: param1=value1&param2=value2 etc.

to correctly handle "|" you'll need to parse the entire param *as one string*: "Tom|Jerry" and then use string manipulation to split the string at the "|" char, and get the names.