# Python flask not getting URL parameters

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm working on a simple REST service with flask, the method deleteTweets() can't retrieve the URL parameter i'm sending, so tried to print to see what is sending but i get this error line.

```
  File "C:\Path\HomeController.py", line 26, in deleteTwee
ts
    id = request.args.get['id']
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2018 12:00:05] "DELETE /api/deleteTweet?id=ABC HTTP/1.1" 500
```

This the code:

```
import json
import Service
from flask import Flask, render_template,jsonify,request


app = Flask(__name__)

apiUrl='/api'


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("/home.html", code=400)

@app.route(apiUrl+'/getData', methods=['GET'])
def test_request():
    list = [15,21,8]
    return jsonify(list)

@app.route(apiUrl+'/getTweets', methods=['GET'])
def request():
    return Service.getAlltwits()

@app.route(apiUrl+'/deleteTweet', methods=['DELETE'])
def deleteTweets():
    id = request.args.get['id'] 
    print(id)
    return
```

It's very simple but not sure what i did missed.
also tried with   `id = request.args.get('id')`

Comment: Anytime you get an `AttributeError`, it helps to `print(request.__dict__)` and `print(dir(request))`. This will show you the possible attrs and methods of a given object. Then you don't have to guess about what is accessible.

Comment: Also, `request` is a function, not an object. So you should call it if you plan on invoking its functionality: `request()`

Comment: @JacobIRR That's odd since i based my code in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/python-flask-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url

Comment: Defining your own function named `request` overwrites the `from flask import request` you did at the top.

Comment: `@app.route(apiUrl+'/getTweets', methods=['GET'])
def request():
    return Service.getAlltwits()`
you have function named "request", thats why you are getting "function' object has no attribute 'args'"

Comment: Ah, so you have a name conflict. request vs request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing the correct thing - and you're importing `request`.

But you have a function named `request` as well, and this function overwrites the former name (which is the actual flask request):

```
@app.route(apiUrl+'/getTweets', methods=['GET'])
def request():
    return Service.getAlltwits()
```

Change the name to `get_tweets` instead:

```
@app.route(apiUrl+'/getTweets', methods=['GET'])
def get_tweets():
    return Service.getAlltwits()
```

Comment: ooh i feel dumb that i didn't notice that

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a function called `request`, which has therefore hidden the global request variable. Rename your route function.