# Flask/Rest Get a string from another web service

Tags: python, mysql, rest, flask

I have two web services called getCourseCodeWS and checkStudentOnCourseWS both with 1 corresponding DB. The first WS returns a courseCode from a DB. This courseCode should work as a parameter in my checkStudentOnCourseWS which should use the courseCode + another parameter called personalIdentityNumber, which I get from checkStudentOnCourseWS's DB. This should return a true/false depending on if the arguments match the database, in other words, if the student appears in the course.

My question is how do I request the actual respons I get from my getCourseCodeWS to work as an argument for checkStudentOnCourseWS?

```
@app.route('/courses/<course>/<period>', methods= ["GET"])
def checkCourseCodeWS(course, period):
myCursor2 = mydb.cursor()

query2 = ("SELECT courseCode FROM paraplyet.courseInfo WHERE courseName = " + "'" + course + "' AND duration = " + "'" + period + "'")
myCursor2.execute(query2)
myresult2 = myCursor2.fetchall()

return jsonify(myresult2)
```

Comment: do you mean requests.get(url_for(checkCourseCodeWS)) in side the other method?

Comment: What is happening when you run the above code? From what I can tell, it's missing a semicolon, and you don't escape your parameters. The latter is only a security issue. It should still function without it.

Comment: @noslenkwah I get the return I want. I write courses/<course>/<period>, for example 127.0.0.1:5000/courses/D0024E/HT2017 and get the matching CourseCode in json format which I want. The problem I am having is: How do I build checkStudentOnCourseWS which should use the courseCode I get from checkCourseCodeWS as a parameter in my next WS. 
Short and basic explanation of my checkStudentOnCourseWS. I want to use the courseCode respond from 1st WS and also another parameter called studentID to validate if a student is signed for a course (that is the courseCode).

Comment: @E.Serra Do u have an example on how I can use that request url? Not 100% sure I understand your question. Maybe the comment I did above makes it more clear.

Comment: when your go somewhere with your browser, it is issuing a GET request, meaning it is telling the server lkistening it wants to GET whatever is linked to that uri.
This looks to be exactly what you want to do, e.g. one of your methods needs to use the result of another method (probably somewhere else), so you can issue a get requests inside that method to get the result of the other one.
THOUGH porobably the best option is for you to call one of the methods inside the other one:

Comment: @Milletarp You don't have to use `course, period` as function argument at all.