# Passing Javascript array in Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm developing and application with `python flask` and I want to send the return value of a `Javascript` function(an array) to a `python` function. Given below is the code.

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  function getVals(){
      a = [ab, cd];
      return a;
  }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="/end_stu_live_session">End This</a>
```

**Python**

```
@app.route('/end_stu_live_session')
def end_stu_live_session():
   return render_template('stu_dashboard.html')
```

I want the array from the Javascript function `getVals()` to be passed to the python function `end_stu_live_session`. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Flask how to get parameters from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/python-flask-how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

- You can send the return value of a Javascript function(an array) to a Python method via Ajax as JSON.
- Send `contentType: 'application/json'` from AJAX and receiving the data as `request.json` in Flask.

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/end_stu_live_session',methods=["GET", "POST"])
def end_stu_live_session():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        return jsonify(data)
    return render_template("home.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

**home.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flask Ajax</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="data"></div>       
        <button id="demo_btn">Dummy button</button>
        <script>
            function getVals(){
                  a = ["ab", "cd"];
                  return a;
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#demo_btn").on("click", function() {
                    var js_data = JSON.stringify(getVals());
                    $.ajax({                        
                        url: '/end_stu_live_session',
                        type : 'post',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data : js_data
                    }).done(function(result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        $("#data").html(result);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("fail: ",textStatus, errorThrown);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: flask ajax request]