# Change image source from another drive with an ajax call to flask

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I want to change an image when I click on it with an image from another drive. For this I created this python function:

```
@main.route('/tester/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def tester():
    if request.method == "GET":
        test_img = "D:\TBV_Data\MS_CO_Front_20120403_140154_0001140_006.png"
        return send_file(test_img, mimetype='image/png')
```

I request this data by the following function:

```
function testFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tester', //server url
        type: 'GET',    //passing data as post method
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#myimage9").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data);
        },
    });
};
```

The outcome of the "src" of the image is, unfortunately, a load of weird data:

```
<img id="myimage9" src="data:image/png;base64,�PNG
IHDR�I!�IDATx���׮mK�&amp;�}�;��morg��c�V��)C�� B��.�(z�� ��� ��*��B�y2�I��^~��]D�1��ÁDb�9��&amp;�E����o-���OZl��/_���NJ��%�%�т���6�ݴw�~��EE���-�[p�z^3Y����8��#�
```

I can imagine that I didn't encode the image correctly. Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
I tried to encode the data to base64 with:

```
function utoa(str) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
};
```

This will unfortunately just changes the data to the following, but will not show the image:

```
<img id="myimage9" src="data:image/png;base64,/VBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABRAAAAP9CAIAAAAUSSH9AAEAAElEQVR4/f397m1L/Sb9ff0OO/39bW9yZ/39Y/0dVv39KUP9/SBC/f0u/Sh6A
```

Comment: When you use `<img src="/tester/">` what happens?

Comment: This was it! Wished I had read your answer sooner, but thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: BTW, did you notice that your Ajax call says `'GET'`, directly contradicting the comment on that line, which says `//passing data as post method`? Never comment the obvious, then these things cannot happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, add a `filename` variable to your route:

```
import os
from flask import request, send_from_directory

IMAGE_DIR = r"D:\TBV_Data"

@main.route('/tester/<filename>')
def tester(filename):
    return send_from_directory(IMAGE_DIR, filename)
```

This uses the [`send_from_directory` function](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) to make sure that the client cannot download files from *outside* the designated directory by entering filenames that contain things like `\..\` (this is known as "directory traversal attack").

And on the client side:

```
function testFunc(selector, filename) {
    $(selector).attr("src", "/tester/" + encodeURIComponent(filename) );
}
```

The use of `encodeURIComponent()` is good style and prevents problems with filenames that contain special characters. The browser will request the image as soon as its `src` attribute changes, there is no need to do anything via Ajax here.

---

Preventing a directory traversal attack with `send_file()` alone is a bit more involved:

```
filepath = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, filename))
if os.path.commonprefix([filepath, IMAGE_DIR]) != IMAGE_DIR:
    abort(404)

return send_file(filepath)
```

File paths on Windows are case-insensitive, so `IMAGE_DIR` should contain the *actual* case of the path, otherwise this test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
function testFunc(args) {
        selector = args.data[0];
        filename = args.data[1];
        var obj = JSON.stringify({"data" : filename});
        console.log(obj);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/tester2/', //server url
            type: 'GET',    //passing data as post method
            data: obj,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $(selector).attr("src", "/tester2/");
            },
        });
    };
```

I was assigning the raw data to the src attribute, but I needed to assign the URL of the GET request to the src attribute.

Comment: Not a good solution. There is no reason whatsoever to call `$.ajax()` at all here. Remove that entire Ajax call and replace it by `$("#myimage9").attr("src", "/tester/");`

Comment: But what if I want to change the image in "/tester/" on the server-side by data send from the client-side? Is there a better way than an ajax call?

Comment: Just set the `src` attribute again. The browser will issue a new HTTP request when the `src` attribute of an image changes. You can set the img src to something with URL parameters, if you want to.

Comment: If you want to prevent the client from caching the image, let the server send an appropriate `Cache-Control` header along with the image. This can be useful if you want serve changing images under the same URL, but *ideally* the same URL always loads the same image, in which case the client may cache it.

Comment: Yes but how will I send the file name from the client-side to the server-side to before I change the src attribute?

Comment: I'm not following. Your code samples send nothing to the server.

Comment: Sorry I have updated my Ajax call it is the following now (see my anwer)
  }; `

Comment: You are making things much too complicated. Edit your server side route handler so that it [accepts query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24892035/18771) (don't use JSON, there is no need for JSON here). Test the server side by opening `/tester/?data=some_filename.jpg` in the browser and load a few different files by changing the URL parameter. When that works, use `$("#myimage9").attr("src", "/tester/" + $.param({data: filename}) );` in the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201341/discussion-between-brian-barbieri-and-tomalak).

Comment: I've just added my own answer, have a look.