# How to write data to iframe via Flask POST method

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have an old application based on Python SimpleHTTPServer that I'm trying to convert to Flask.

In the old application, I had an HTML form that was submitting a POST request to the SimpleHTTPServer. The form also had an iframe. There, I had a do_POST method that was reading the values in the text boxes and producing some results. I then wrapped the results into a JSON object and wrote to the wfile method of SIMPLEHTTPServer. This caused the result to get populated into the iframe. The iframe had an onload method on the JS side and here, the results would be read from it and populated into various text-boxes.

I now want to convert this to Flask from SimpleHTTPServer. What is the best way to translate the logic I have in place to Flask? Basically, what is the equivalent of writing to the wfile object?

Also, on the Flask side, I also have some @app.route methods where I can form a URL with input parameters and get the results as JSON objects (example: http://localhost/calculate?input1=3&input2=5). Is it possible to leverage these URLs instead of the POST request to get the result into JavaScript?

Comment: Here is how you can read query params in flask
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24892131/3358570

Comment: Thanks. That I can do. I can also return the result of some python function that runs on those query parameters in a JSON. Now, I want to construct the URL, pass to Flask, get the JSON result and parse it out in JS. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is hello world of flask to get the data from URL parameters and do the stuff and return a json

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    param1 = request.args.get('param1')
    param2 = request.args.get('param2')
    res = param1 + param2
    return jsonify({
        "result": res
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

example request

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/?param1=hi&param2=there
```

Example response

```
{
    "result": "hithere"
}
```