# How todo a GET method that can take different types of arguments in python?

Tags: python, flask, get, webapi

GET /users?city="Seattle"

GET /users/{userId}

GET /users

So what im trying todo is that if they do a GET they can either find  users by there city or by there ID or if they just do users they get all the users.

```
class Users(Resource):
def get(self,id=None):
    if id is None:
        #this return all users
    else:
        #this returns a user with specfic id 
        #the next part im trying todo is return all users from a specfic city
```

Comment: This is often done using rewrite rules in the webserver

Comment: This really depends on what library or framework you're using to write your web server. Perhaps you can add some information about that to the question? I'd strongly recommend against rolling your own - it's generally a bad idea, especially if you're still struggling with the basics. Use a few good ones, then decide if you can do better. Flask, Quart, Django, Pyramid, there's lots of options. The aspect you're asking about is generally 'routing'.

Comment: Im using flask for this

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46321103/8228558

Comment: And this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385027/8228558

Comment: inside `else` you will have to get `request.args.get('city')` and check if it has some value on `None`.