# Redirecting in Flask with path from url

Tags: python, flask

I am running into a problem trying to redirect in Flask using the following:

```py
 @views.route('/dash_monitoring/<path:url>')
 @login_required
 def monitoring_page(url):
     return redirect("/home/dash_monitoring/{}".format(url))
```

The url in `<path:url>` is in the format `https://somesite.com/detail/?id=2102603` but when I try to print it in the function, it prints `https://somesite.com/detail` only without the id part,so it obviously redirects to `/home/dash_monitoring/https://somesite.com/detail` instead of `/home/dash_monitoring/https://somesite.com/detail/?id=2102603`.

What should I do so it keeps the id part and redirects to the right url?

Comment: Have already tried the solution present over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892035/how-can-i-get-the-named-parameters-from-a-url-using-flask?

Comment: @TajinderSingh I have just tried and it is not working. From what I understand in the thread you shared, the id could be retrieved that way if it were an URL parameter. But in my case the whole url,  which I need to use in the redirected url, is appended to `/dash/monitoring` . Instead, I want it to be appended to `/home/dash/monitoring`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.url` and imply string manipulation:

```
@views.route('/dash_monitoring/<path:url>')
@login_required
def monitoring_page(url):
    parsed_path = request.url.split('/dash_monitoring/')[1]
    #return the parsed path
    return redirect("/home/dash_monitoring/{}".format(parsed_path))
```

Alternatively, you can iterate through `request.args` for creating query string and construct path with args

```
@views.route('/dash_monitoring/<path:url>')
@login_required
def monitoring_page(url):
    query_string = ''
    for arg,value in request.args.items():
        query_string+=f"{arg}={value}&"
    query_string=query_string[:-1] # to remove & at the end
    path=f"{path}?{query_string}"
    #return the parsed path
    return redirect(f"/home/dash_monitoring/{path}")
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This has an easy solution, we use the `url_for` function:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<name>')
def index(name):
     return f"Hello {name}!"

@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
     return redirect(url_for('index',name = 'John'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug = True)
```

1. In my code we firs import `redirect` and `url_for`.
2. We create 2 routes `index` and `admin`.
3. In `index` route we output a simple response with the named passed to the url. So if we get `example.com/John` it will output `Hello John!`.
4. In `admin` route we redirect the user to `index` route because it's not the admin (**This is a simple example that can you can model with what you want**). The `index` route needs a name so we pass inside the `url_for` function some context so it can desplay the name.