# Printing an int list in a single line python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to scan multiple numbers separated by spaces (let's assume '1 2 3' as an example) in a single line and add it to a list of int. I did it by using:

```
#gets the string 
string = input('Input numbers: ') 
#converts the string into an array of int, excluding the whitespaces
array = [int(s) for s in string.split()]
```

Apparently it works, since when I type in '1 2 3' and do a `print(array)` the output is:

> [1, 2, 3]

But I want to print it in a single line without the brackets, and with a space in between the numbers, like this:

> 1 2 3

I've tried doing:

```
for i in array:
    print(array[i], end=" ")
```

But I get an error:

> 2 3 Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> print(array[i], end=" ")
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

How can I print the list of ints (assuming my first two lines of code are right) in a single line, and without the brackets and commas?

Comment: `i` in your for loop is an element from your array not an index.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You want to say

```
for i in array:
    print(i, end=" ")
```

The syntax `i in array` iterates over each member of the list.  So, `array[i]` was trying to access `array[1]`, `array[2]`, and `array[3]`, but the last of these is out of bounds (`array` has indices 0, 1, and 2).

You can get the same effect with `print(" ".join(map(str,array)))`.

Answer (score 94):

Yes that is possible in **Python 3**, just use `*` before the variable like:

```
print(*list)
```

This will print the list separated by spaces.

(where `*` is the *unpacking* operator that turns a list into positional arguments, `print(*[1,2,3])` is the same as `print(1,2,3)`, see also [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/2314737))

Comment: I ended up using this as follows `print(*list, end="\t")`

Answer (score 22):

Try using join on a str conversion of your ints:

```
print(' '.join(str(x) for x in array))
```

For python 3.7

Comment: That also works, and it's even better because it adds an end of line after it finishes printing the list, thank you!

Comment: That also works fine with Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 18):

these will both work in Python 2.7 and Python 3.x:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(' '.join(str(x) for x in l))
1 2 3
>>> print(' '.join(map(str, l)))
1 2 3
```

btw, `array` is a reserved word in Python.

Comment: `array` is [not a reserved keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library) in Python, you're thinking of `list` or `bytearray`

Comment: The list comprehension `str(x) for x in l` is more pythonic than `map()`. `map()` [was almost removed from Python](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) because you can always use a list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 11):

You have multiple options, each with different general use cases.

The first would be to use a `for` loop, as you described, but in the following way.

```
for value in array:
    print(value, end=' ')
```

You could also use `str.join` for a simple, readable one-liner using comprehension. This method would be good for storing this value to a variable.

```
print(' '.join(str(value) for value in array))
```

My favorite method, however, would be to pass `array` as `*args`, with a `sep` of `' '`. Note, however, that this method will only produce a `print`ed output, not a value that may be stored to a variable.

```
print(*array, sep=' ')
```

Comment: for value in array:
    print(value, end=' ')                                                                                                   in this situation if array contains 5 'items' message will appears 5 times                 
just use print(*array)

Answer (score 4):

If you write

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(*a, sep = ',')
```

You get this output: `1,2,3,4,5`

Answer (score 2):

```
# Print In One Line Python

print('Enter Value')

n = int(input())

print(*range(1, n+1), sep="")
```

Comment: Using the star operator is a clever solution. Note, however, that the question actually uses an arbitrary list that is answered, whereas your answer uses a range from 1 to a single input. Also, you likely meant to use `sep=" "` rather than `sep=""`

Answer (score 2):

```
lstofGroups=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print(*lstofGroups, sep = ',')
```

don't forget to put * before the List

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7 another trick is:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
for num in arr:
  print num,
# will print 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use more elements "end" in print:

```
for iValue in arr:
   print(iValue, end = ", ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this code will help you.

```py
>>> def sort(lists):
...     lists.sort()
...     return lists
...
>>> datalist = [6,3,4,1,3,2,9]
>>> print(*sort(datalist), end=" ")
1 2 3 3 4 6 9
```

you can use an empty list variable to collect the user input, with method append().
and if you want to print list in one line you can use `print(*list)`