# How to print list elements in one line?

Tags: python

I need to print the sorted list of integers, but it should be in a line and without the list square brackets and without any '\n' in the end...

```
import random
n = int(input(""))
l=[]
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    l.append(x)
not_sorted = True
while not_sorted:    
    x = random.randint(0,n-1)
    y = random.randint(0,n-1)
    while x==y:
        y = random.randint(0,n-1)
    if x>y:
        if l[x]<l[y]:
            (l[x],l[y])=(l[y],l[x])
    if x<y:
        if l[x]>l[y]:
            (l[x],l[y])=(l[y],l[x])
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        if l[i]>l[i+1]:
            break
    else:
       not_sorted = False
for i in range(n):
    print(l[i])
```

output should be like this:::  1 2 3 4 5
and not like this :::: [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @Cut7er "without the list square brackets"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: multiple prints on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-multiple-prints-on-the-same-line)

Comment: @kyouma How is all the sorting code relevant to the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing an int list in a single line python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625208/printing-an-int-list-in-a-single-line-python3)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can unpack the list to `print` using `*` which will automatically split by a space

```
print(*l)
```

if you want a comma, use the `sep=` argument

```
print(*l, sep=', ')
```

Comment: Is this only for Python 3.0 and later?  This doesn't work for Python 2.7

Comment: why on earth are you still using python 2.7?! It's over 10 years old! If you want to do this on python 2, you'll need to do `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: There are some Python packages that changed in Python 3.0, which would require a not-insignificant code change.

Yes, Python 2.7 is over 10 years old.  For 10+ years, I wrote code in Python 2.7.  The code didn't just upgrade automatically when Python 3.0 came along.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
for i in range(n):
    print(l[i], end=' ')
```

Or

```
print(*l, end=' ')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that.
The only thing, items in a list should be strings, not integers

```
import random

n = int(input(""))
l = []

for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    l.append(x)

not_sorted = True

while not_sorted:    
    x = random.randint(0, n-1)
    y = random.randint(0, n-1)
    while x == y:
        y = random.randint(0, n-1)
    if x > y:
        if l[x] < l[y]:
            (l[x], l[y]) = (l[y], l[x])
    if x < y:
        if l[x] > l[y]:
            (l[x], l[y]) = (l[y], l[x])

    for i in range(0, n-1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            break
    else:
       not_sorted = False

print(', '.join([str(l[i]) for i in range(n)]))
```

Answer (score -1):

For the list of string, I do it this way....

```
listChar = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

someChar = ""

for n in listChar:
  someChar = someChar + n

print(someChar)

Res: abcd
```

Answer (score -1):

Use enumerate to generate count(0-indexed) for each value. To print them on the same line use can use the `end` keyword

```py
    for idx, val in enumerate(list_name):
         print(val, end = " ")
```