# How print the returned tuple of a function without parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def CountFrequency(z): 
  
    
    freq = {} 
    for item in z: 
        if (item in freq): 
            freq[item] += 1
        else: 
            freq[item] = 1
  
    for key, value in freq.items(): 
        a=(min(freq.values()))
        b=(max(freq.values()))
    return a,b
```

**i want to print my output without brackets but it prints with ( )**

eg -

expected :

```
1 2
```

output :

```
(1,2)
```

Comment: `print(* CountFrequency(whatever))` - the * will decompose the list and then prints standard -`sep=" "` will take care of the space between 1 and 2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097264/how-to-print-list-elements-in-one-line  for some more explanations - works for list the same

Comment: @PatrickArtner damn how can i forget this concept. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Can also do `' '.join(map(str, CountFrequency(z)))` if you want to construct the string but not necessarily print it.

Answer (score 4):

The return type is of [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) type, therefore the parenthesis (it's their string representation).

To print tuple elements separated with spaces you can use the `*` operator:

```
t = a, b = 3, 5

print(*t)
```