# joining output from regex search

Tags: python, python-3.x

- I have a regex that looks for numbers in a file.
- I put results in a list

The problem is that it prints each results on a new line for every single number it finds. it aslo ignore the list I've created.

What I want to do is to have all the numbers into one list.
I used join() but it doesn't works.

code :

```
def readfile():
    regex = re.compile('\d+')
for num in regex.findall(open('/path/to/file').read()):
    lst = [num]
    jn = ''.join(lst)    
    print(jn)
```

output :

```
122
34
764
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `regex.findall()` returns a list and you are are joining in each iteration and printing it.

That is why you're seeing this problem.

You can try something like this.

> numbers.txt

```
Xy10Ab
Tiger20
Beta30Man
56
My45one
```

> statements:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> lst = []
>>>
>>> for num in regex.findall(open('numbers.txt').read()):
...     lst.append(num)
...
>>> lst
['10', '20', '30', '56', '45']
>>>
>>> jn = ''.join(lst)
>>>
>>> jn
'1020305645'
>>>
>>> jn2 = '\n'.join(lst)
>>> jn2
'10\n20\n30\n56\n45'
>>>
>>> print(jn2)
10
20
30
56
45
>>>
>>> nums = [int(n) for n in lst]
>>> nums
[10, 20, 30, 56, 45]
>>>
>>> sum(nums)
161
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

**What goes wrong:**

> ```
> # this iterates the single numbers you find - one by one
> for num in regex.findall(open('/path/to/file').read()):  
>     lst = [num]                  # this puts one number back into a new list
>     jn = ''.join(lst)            # this gets the number back out of the new list
>     print(jn)                    # this prints one number
> ```

**Fixing it**:

Reading [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) show's you, it returns a list already.

There is no(t much) need to use a `for` on it to print it.

If you want a list - simply use `re.findall()`'s return value - if you want to print it, use one of the methods in [Printing an int list in a single line python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625208/printing-an-int-list-in-a-single-line-python3?rq=1) (several more posts on SO about printing in one line):

```
import re

my_r = re.compile(r'\d+')                 # define pattern as raw-string

numbers = my_r.findall("123 456 789")     # get the list

print(numbers)

# different methods to print a list on one line
# adjust sep  / end to fit your needs
print( *numbers, sep=", ")                # print #1

for n in numbers[:-1]:                    # print #2
    print(n, end = ", ")
print(numbers[-1])

print(', '.join(numbers))                 # print #3
```

Output:

```
['123', '456', '789']   # list of found strings that are numbers
123, 456, 789
123, 456, 789
123, 456, 789
```

Doku:

- [print() function for `sep=` and `end=`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)
- [Printing an int list in a single line python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625208/printing-an-int-list-in-a-single-line-python3?rq=1)
- [Convert all strings in a list to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int) ... if you need the list as numbers

---

More on printing in one line:

- [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)
- [Python: multiple prints on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-multiple-prints-on-the-same-line)
- [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)
- [Print new output on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032214/print-new-output-on-same-line)

Answer (score -1):

Use list built-in functions to append new values.

```
def readfile():
regex = re.compile('\d+')
lst = []

for num in regex.findall(open('/path/to/file').read()):
    lst.append(num)

print(lst)
```