# Is it possible to name a variable 'in' in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, units-of-measurement, unit-conversion

I am making a unit converter for a homework assignment, and I am using abbreviations for the various units of measurement as variable names, but when I try to define 'in' as a variable, it thinks I mean to use the word 'in' as if I wanted to say 'for x in y' or something like that, and I get the following error:

```
  File "unit_converter-v1.py", line 13
    in = 12
     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to get around this?

I know I could just use the word 'inch' or 'inches' but then I would have to type 'inch' or 'inches' into the program every time I needed to convert inches, and I want to make the process as efficient as possible (I'm a senior in highschool, and my phisics teacher will allow us to use unit converters on tests and quizzes if we write the code ourselves. The point is that time is valuable and I need to be as time-efficient as possible).

Comment: Why would you want to get around this and not just rename it?

Comment: Oh no... Two more characters for `inch`. Use an IDE, get autocomplete. Time efficiency multipled!

Comment: The best thing you can do to make the process more efficient is to choose your battles. in vs inch is not going to make a lot of difference.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin - Yea, but if you give them an inch...

Comment: If the point is to save time, why not just name it `i`...

Comment: Why not literally `12`? Also two characters

Comment: Why not just change the case of `in` to `In` or `IN`?

Comment: @Nicarus ...they fork the interpreter and rename the keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` is a python keyword, so no you cannot use it as a variable or function or class name.

See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords for the list of keywords in Python 2.7.12.

Answer (score 2):

**in** is a reserved word, so you won't be able to use it as a variable name; the easiest solution would be to use a different name.

Python makes it easier to identify reserved words with the `keyword.iskeyword` function, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library)

BTW, naming things was described as the most difficult task for a developer by itworld [this article](http://www.itworld.com/article/2823759/enterprise-software/124383-Arg-The-9-hardest-things-programmers-have-to-do.html#slide10).

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers state, you can't. However, you can simply change the case of it as an alternative.

`In = 2` is valid and will work. So would any other variation with at least one of the characters capitalized.