# Initialize a set() as argument of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a recursive function, that takes a new `set()` as argument. This is the function:

```
def attributes(node, set):
    set.add(node.tag)
    if not node.istext():
        for n in node.content:
            set = set.intersection(attributes(node, set()))
    return set
```

but I get this error:

```
error -> TypeError
'set' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you post the way you are calling it with some sample input/

Comment: Don't call your variable `set`, that shadows the built-in type `set`. You probably mean something like `def attributes(node,myset=set())`, but watch out for mutable function parameters (that only get initialized once).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the list of Python reserved words and builtins available in a library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library)

Comment: Actually a good example of why you shouldn't name variables from their type but from their function <g>

Comment: i call this function in another function: 
`def statistiche(fhtml, k1, k2):
    a=set()
    tup=(attributes(parse(fhtml), set), 5)`

Answer (score 5):

You are overwriting the global builtin `set` with your local parameter. Just change it to

```
def attributes(node, my_set):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are using a datatype(set) reserved by Python itself and which you should not use as your variable name so change the name:

```
def attributes(node, the_set):
    the_set.add(node.tag)
    if not node.istext():
        for n in node.content:
            the_set = the_set.intersection(attributes(n, set()))
    return the_set
```

Comment: `set` is _not_  a "reserved keyword" - else the OP would get a `SyntaxError` at import time.

Comment: true but in some way it is treated like one

Comment: @gianlucagabriele of course - the line `the_set = the_set.intersection(attributes(node, the_set()))` is wrong and should be `the_set = the_set.intersection(attributes(node, set()))`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, ok nice but now i have another error:
`maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: There's another typo in the code - it should actually be `the_set = the_set.intersection(attributes(n, set()))`