# Gunicorn ImportError: No module name app only when directory name is site

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Trying to get gunicorn runing with a hello world app.
This is my project directory structure

```
Project
  |_ config
  |  |_ ___init__.py
  |  |_ settings.py
  |
  |_ instance
  |  |_settings.py_production
  |
  |_ site
  |  |_ __init__.py
  |  |_ app.py
  |
  |_ .env
  |_ docker-compose.yml
  |_ Dockerfile
  |_ requirements.txt
```

I am running this in a docker container but when I go into the container in interactive mode the same behaviour occurs.

When the directory is named `site` and  I run the command `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - "site.app:create_app()"` I get an error `ImportError: No module name app`.  However if I name the directory `foo`, `snakeeyes` or `blah` I do not recieve an error and the app runs as expected.  Is there a reason for this?  Can directories not be named site?  Are there any other restreicted direcory names in python?

Comment: You shouldn't call your module the same as any module which is a part of the Python standard library as depending on the ordering of the module import path, you will get the wrong one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`site` is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) in python. I assume, but am not positive, that you are experiencing a conflict.

`site` is not a reserved word in python . You can check out this SO post if you're interested in the standard keywords: [Is the list of Python reserved words and builtins available in a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library)

I think you might be able to test whether this is a conflict by suppressing the automatic import of the library as directed by the documentation:

```
This module is automatically imported during initialization. The automatic import can be suppressed using the interpreter’s -S option.
```

Comment: running `gunicorn -S -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - "pickle.app:create_app()"` threw an error saying the -S wasn't a valid option.  I did however take a look at the list here https://docs.python.org/3/contents.html under improved modules where site is located.  I renamed everything to another module `pickle` and got the same `ImportError: No module named app` result. I beleve this is the correct answer.

Comment: Gunicorn isn't an interpreter of python. The documentation is referring to the actual call to python. So, something like `python -S`.  If you wanted to try that experiment you would need to figure out how to pass command line arguments to the python interpreter through gunicorn.