# How to print list with " { list } " brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a `list` with `{}` curly braces.
For example:

```
the_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

and I want to print the list as

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do not name lists `list` in python. It overrides the builtin `list`

Comment: Also, if all the values in your list are unique, you can `print(set(your_list))` ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this like this:

`print('{' + ', '.join([str(x) for x in the_list]) + '}')`

`', '.join` joins each element with a `', '`

`[str(x) for x in the_list]` makes each number a string so it can be joined as above.

Comment: Even shorter: `'{' + ', '.join(map(str, the_list)) + '}'`.

Comment: Not really: I'm trying to introduce higher-order functions to a Python beginner :)

Comment: Try to never concatenate strings, as it clutters readability and has poor performance issues (as soon as you concatenate more than 2 strings!)

Answer (score 5):

> print(str(list).replace('[','{').replace(']','}'))

this converts the list to a string and replaces "[]" with "{}"

Comment: This is a hack on the representation of the list. Please use the items of the list instead.

Comment: this works for op so its good enough... simple question simple answer no need for complexity @SamuelGIFFARD

Comment: 3.x question should get answer for 3.x

Comment: No, it's a _complex_ answer, because it goes against the nature of the data structure and uses irrelevant details. It's also slow.

Comment: @9000 No, it is faster.  I measured using timeit.  For the short list of 3, this method takes  3/4 of the time required for GIFFARDS map answer.  For long lists (10000) the advantage grows to 1/2 the time (twice as fast).

Comment: At least someone comes with some actual proof and it proves me right nice try ;) thanks for the info @TerryJanReedy

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: I ran `timeit`, and I stand corrected! Indeed, apparently both `str(list)` and `str.replace` are very optimized in Python, and iteration / generation using explicit function calls is pretty expensive in comparison.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2, try:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print '{{{}}}'.format(', '.join(map(str, my_list)))
```

In Python 3, try:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(f'{{{", ".join(map(str, my_list))}}}')
```

### Explanation:

#### Format

Whenever you're looking to get one of your objects in a specific format, check `.format()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

It uses `{}` as placeholders (can be made more complex, that's just a simple example). And to escape `{` and `}`, just double it, like so: `"{{ }}"`. This latter string, after formatting, will become `"{ }"`.

In Python 3, you now have f-strings https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/
They work the same as `''.format()` but they are more readable: `''.format()` => `f''`.

#### Casting elements into str

Then, you want all your elements (in the `list`) to be transformed into strings -> `map(str, my_list)`.

#### Joining elements

And then, you want to glue each of these elements with `", "`. In Python, there is a function that does just that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

`', '.join(my_iterable)` will do it.

#### Reserved keywords

And last but not least, do not name your list `list`. Otherwise, you'll rewrite the builtin `list` and you won't be able to use `lists` anymore.
Check this answer for a good list of these keywords: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/8933502

Comment: Question is tagged with 3.x, so add the parens needed for 3.x.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Just realized that. I've added the Python 3 answer. Thanks for pointing this out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get hacky:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> '{%s}' % str(l).strip('[]')
>>> {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to answering this question:

A. Modify str(alist) by replacing [] with {}. @Garret modified the str result calling str.replace twice.  Another approach is to use str.translate to make both changes at once.  A third, and the fastest I found, is to slice off [ and ], keep the content, and add on { and }.

B. Calculate what str(alist)[1:-1] calculates but in Python code and embed the result in {...}. With CPython, the multiple replacements proposed for building the content string are much slower:

```
import timeit

expressions = (  # Orderd by timing results, fastest first.
    "'{' + str(alist)[1:-1] + '}'",
    "str(alist).replace('[','{').replace(']','}')",
    "str(alist).translate(table)",
    "'{' + ', '.join(map(str, alist)) + '}'",
    "'{{{}}}'.format(', '.join(map(str, alist)))",
    "'{' + ', '.join(str(c) for c in alist) + '}'",
    )

alist = [1,2,3]
table = str.maketrans('[]', '{}')
for exp in expressions:
    print(eval(exp))  # Visually verify that exp works correctly.

alist = [1]*100  # The number can be varied.
n =1000
for exp in expressions:
    print(timeit.timeit(exp, number=n, globals=globals()))
```

Results with 64-bit 3.7.0b2 on Windows 10:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
0.009153687000000021
0.009371952999999988
0.009818325999999988
0.018995990000000018
0.019342450999999983
0.028495214999999963
```

The relative results are about the same for 1000 and 10000.

EDIT: @Mike Müller independently posted the slice expression, embedded in the following two expressions, with essentially the same timings as the top expression above.

```
"f'{{{str(alist)[1:-1]}}}'",
"'{%s}' % str(alist)[1:-1]",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
('{}'.format(the_list)).replace('[','{').replace(']','}')
```

Result

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: This works, but let's face it, it's a terrible practice.

Comment: @9000: The whole thing is peculiar anyway.

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to use the heavy machinery of `.format`, why not `"{{{0}}}".format(', '.join(...))`.

Comment: Definitely. I'm adamant about this. I use `.format` wherever possible. In fact any time I can make my code more abstruse I do it. It's bait.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.6 f-strings:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(f'{{{str(lst)[1:-1]}}}')
{1, 2, 3}
```

or with `format` for Python < 3.6:

```
>>> print('{{{}}}'.format(str(lst)[1:-1]))
{1, 2, 3}
```

or with the old, but not deprecated `%`:

```
>>> print('{%s}' % str(lst)[1:-1])
{1, 2, 3}
```