# Django site preview not updating after model.py change

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning django and I am working on models. I created a Product class

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    int = models.IntegerField(default=10)
```

and I am trying to delete the 'int' field but the django site does not update
after the chanage.

After deleting a model field(the 'int' field, see the screenshots),
and running

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

the live preview does not update and throws an error regarding the erased field. after closing the server and restarting the server(ctrl + c and than
`python manage.py runserver` the page updates and does not throw any errors

I am using sqlite. I tried deleting '**pycache**' and all the migrations also db.sql3, recreating the superuser but after removing any field I still get the same error.

picture 1 -> initial state `$` https://ibb.co/Yb6pmgr
picture 2 -> after removing 'int' field  https://ibb.co/xf1bJQJ
picture 3 -> error : `$` https://ibb.co/0cPyRZv

Comment: Not really clear what you are saying, can you please edit your post and make it easier to read?

Comment: @ArnavPoddar I edited the question, hope is clear now

Comment: If you have the data that you're trying to add into the table backed up somewhere why don't you try dropping the table completely and deleting all migrations and then make migrations again?

Comment: @LeroyJD already done that but it is annoying to this everytime. delete migrations. crreate a super user etc. just for one change..

Comment: You do not have to create the super user everytime, run migrations on your app name alone as python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> that way it won't try to make changes to the auth_user tables and your SU still exists. Won't solve your problem but should save you some time in the future :).

Comment: Can you put up the code that is in the migrations file that was created when you deleted the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stop your server, then do your changes and run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands. Maybe this will work, but you are playing with reserved keyword in Python.

If it's not working, for now just remove the `0001_initial.py` which is placed on `trydjango/src/products/migrations/` path. If you already have some data in your database please backup somewhere. `int` is one of the [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=int#built-in-functions) in Python. Please don't such a naming convention every where in Python. Check the below example, you will get some idea about it.

```py
str_val = '1'

print(str_val)  # 1
print(type(str_val))  # <class 'str'>

int_val = int(str_val)

print(int_val)  # 1
print(type(int_val))  # <class 'int'>
```

It is just a simple example of convert string value into integer value using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=int#t). Let's assign some value to [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=int#t).

```py
# by default
print(int)  # <class 'int'>
print(type(int))  # <class 'type'>

# let's get the previous example again
str_val = '1'

print(str_val)  # 1
print(type(str_val))  # <class 'str'>

# assign some value to int(). (please please please never do such a thing like this)
int = 'assigned string'
print(int)  # 'assigned string'
print(type(int))  # <class 'str'>

int_val = int(str_val)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You'll get an error like that when you execute above code. So [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=int#t) will not convert string to integers further more. Because you broke the rule. Now it's just like a normal variable. Still if you really want to add a variable like `int`, just use `_int` or `int_` and if you want to display column name as `int` just add the `db_column` name.

```py
_int = models.IntegerField(default=10, db_column='int')

# or

int_ = models.IntegerField(default=10, db_column='int')
```

Before you do these changes please stop your server. Then edit, after that run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. I hope this answer will help you somehow.

**UPDATE :**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/6194097) will help you to find all the reserved keyword in Python and don't use any of these as your variable names.

Comment: thank you it worked! I have learned my lesson and will not use 'int' as var name in the futere

Comment: You're welcome @nickk2002, for more information read this [article](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/12/12/naming_things.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/6194097) will help you to find all the reserved keyword in Python.