# Importing a python script from a folder named "python"

Tags: python

I like to organize my data analysis projects with a root folder containing a data folder (named `data`) and a code folder (when I use R, I sometimes name it `R`). When using Python, my code folder would logically be called `python`. My project working directory is the root folder (containing both `data` and `python` folders).

I have multiple files of code in my `python` folder. I would like to import one (let's call it `file2.py`) from another, in an interactive python session. I have tried the following:

`from .python import file2`

However, this does not work because `python` is a reserved word. If I rename the folder to something different, it works. Is there a way to escape the reserved word, or pass the file location as a string to the import? I'm frustrated because all the best alternatives (e.g., `code`, `scripts`) are also reserved words. My project organization is an oft-recommended best practice in R, and I'm hoping there's a parallel in Python.

Comment: `python` is not a [reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library)

Comment: if you are in the folder in which the python folder resides, do from python import file2...make sure it includes a `__init__.py`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem as stated. None of the words you mention are reserved. Is `from .python import file2` actually being run from within a package? From your description, that's not the case; relative imports are only valid from an actual package; that is, there must be a directory *under* the working directory (or *under* another entry in `sys.path`) that has your code in it, and also has a subdirectory named `python`, containing `file2.py`. From your description, `python` is directly under your working directory, so your code should be doing `from python import file2` (no `.`).

Comment: @DerekEden: In Python 3, the `__init__.py` isn't necessary, thanks to [PEP 420: Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: Thank you @DerekEden and @ShadowRanger. `from python import file2` works. I swear I tried that before without success, but it is working now!

Comment: no problem...sometimes from experience you just need someone to hover over your shoulder and watch you do things you've already done and they seem to work XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not running as a package. Therefore, you need to run `from python import file2`, not `from .python import file2`.