# String substitution using regex in Python with overlapping pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find `&&` using regex and substitute it with `and` using Python.
Here is my regex:

```
r"(?=( && ))"
```

test input: `x&& &&& && && x || | ||\|| x`, expected output: `x&& &&& and and x or | ||\|| x`. My Python code:

```
import re

input = "x&& &&& && && x || | ||\|| x"
result = re.sub(r"(?=( && ))", " and ", input)
print(result)
```

My output is: `x&& &&& and  && and  && x || | ||\|| x`. This actually works, but instead of substitution it leaves the original pattern just adds my substitution string when it finds pattern. This is really confusing.

Comment: `re.sub(r"(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)", "and", text)`? You only have a trailing space that overlaps.

Comment: overlap can be control by lookahead, but yuo can limit the overlap to a single end char i.e `[ ]&&(?=[ ])` replace ` and` this way endchar can be reuse (overlap) adjacent  ` &&` if needed. of course you can get fancy and im so great stuiff afnd do assertunz back forward and upside down, but that is up to you

Comment: hundreds of overlapping regex examples on this site, did look a little, yes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capturing group inside a positive lookahead can be used to *extract* overlapping patterns. To replace them, you actually need to *consume* the text, lookarounds do not consume the text they match.

In this case, you only have an overlapping *trailing* space, so you might use either of the two approaches:

```
text = re.sub(r"( )&&(?= )", r"\1and", text)
```

Or, if you need to replace any `&&` that is neither preceded nor followed with any whitespace char, use

```
text = re.sub(r"(?<!\S)&&(?!\S)", r"and", text)
```

Note that `input` is a [Python builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/3832970), you should name your text variable in a different way, say, `text`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. Just to clarify: re.sub(r"( )&&(?= )" means && should be followed by whitespace in order to match our pattern, but we are not going to consume this whitespace when substitution is done. How r"\1and" works? I assume '  &&' needs to be substituted by "and" right?

Comment: @AmacOS `( )` is a capturing group, `\1` backreference refers to this group value. If that is a regular space, you surely can just use `text = re.sub(r" &&(?= )", r" and", text)`. I provided a backreference solution in case you want to use `\s` instead of a literal space to match any whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is consistent with your statement of the problem (sic):

```
I am trying to find " && " and substitute it with " and "
```

Since the output is not what you want there must be a problem with your statement of the problem. I believe you actually want:

I am trying to find `" &&"` followed by a space and substitute it with `" and"`

Once you get that right it's just a matter of translating it to a regular expression:

```
import re

s = 'x&& &&& && && x || | ||\|| x'
print re.sub(r' &&(?= )', ' and', s)
  #=> x&& &&& and and x || | ||\|| x
```

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/WV5tEnXW)

`(?= )` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match is followed by a space.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251399/string-substitution-using-regex-in-python-with-overlapping-pattern#comment110097570_62251476