# Python : append a list to a list

Tags: python, list, append

I'm doing some exercises in Python and I came across a doubt. I have to set a list containing the first three elements of **list**, with the **.append** method. The thing is, I get an assertion error, lists don't match. If I print list_first_3 I get "[['cat', 3.14, 'dog']]", so the double square brackets are the problem. But how can I define the list so the output matches?

```py
list = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
list_first_3.append(list[:3])

    
assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

Comment: Use `list_first_3 = list[:3]`. This will set the value of `list_first_3` to what you want it to be.

Comment: @Henry This is would work in this case specifically but not generally for adding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I got the difference. I was confused because the rules of the exercise didn't mention a for loop to solve it, just. append

Comment: One more very important statement.
You should never ever ever name your variables with reserved words or built-ins. See a way to get this list here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22864250/2831135

Comment: Thanks for the info. The code was in another language and I made a fast translation to show it here, I didn't think of that then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`append` can only add a single value. I think what you may be thinking of is the extend method (or the += operator)

```
list1 = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
list_first_3.extend(list1[:3])

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

or

```
list1 = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
list_first_3 += list1[:3]

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

otherwise you'll need a loop:

```
list1 = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
for value in list1[:3]: list_first_3.append(value) 

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

with `append` but without a loop would be possible using a little `map()` trickery:

```
list1 = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
any(map(list_first_3.append,list1[:3]))

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

Answer (score 2):

When appending a list to a list, the list becomes a new item of the original list:

```
list_first_3 == [["cat", 3.14, "dog"]]
```

You are looking for:

```
list_first_3 += list[:3] # ["cat", 3.14, "dog"]
```

This adds every item from `list` to `list_first_3`.

Also you shouldn't name your variables like inbuilt types like `list`.

If you NEED to append, you could use a for-loop:

```
list_first_three = []
for item in list[:3]:
    list_first_three.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get that. The thing is, using .append is mandatory in this exercise. I guess is it impossible to do it with this method?

Comment: @santoros see my edit

Comment: Thanks! that's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you try to append **a list** to another list.

`list[:3]` will return you the result `["cat", 3.14, "dog"]`
Then, you take that result as a whole and put it as an item in `list_first_3`.
If you want to fix that, you can do:

```py
list = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []
list_first_3 += list[:3]

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"] # Return True
```

And if you insist using `append` method:

```py
list = ["cat", 3.14, "dog", 81, 6, 41]
list_first_3 = []

for item in list[:3]
    list_first_3.append(item)

assert list_first_3 == ["cat", 3.14, "dog"] # Return True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not insisiting lol, it was requirement of the exercise. So the only way is with the for loop.