# How to sort lists that contain letters and numbers?

Tags: python, sorting

I have tried lots of different ways to sort the list, but it never sorts it.

```
list = ['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19', 'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american 
dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9']
```

I want them to all be in order eg:
ep1
ep2
ep3
ep4
ep5

Comment: Side note: Don't name your variable `list`... that already has meaning in Python.

Comment: Please read [mre] - then add your attempt(s) at solving the problem. [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: A [link to natsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort/18415320#18415320)

Answer (score 1):

found an answer by using:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
```

Comment: This will not work correctly - this will treat `S1-EP23` the same as `S12-EP3`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a regular expression pattern with two capturing groups - one for the season number, one for the episode number.
2. Define a custom `key` for the sorting function, which returns a tuple of integers. The episodes will be sorted in ascending order according to these integers.

Code:

```
import re

episodes = [
    'american dad S1-EP1',
    'american dad S1-EP10',
    'american dad S1-EP11',
    'american dad S1-EP12',
    'american dad S1-EP13',
    'american dad S1-EP14',
    'american dad S1-EP15',
    'american dad S1-EP16',
    'american dad S1-EP17',
    'american dad S1-EP18',
    'american dad S1-EP19',
    'american dad S1-EP2',
    'american dad S1-EP20',
    'american dad S1-EP21',
    'american dad S1-EP22',
    'american dad S1-EP23',
    'american dad S1-EP3',
    'american dad S1-EP4',
    'american dad S1-EP5',
    'american dad S1-EP6',
    'american dad S1-EP7',
    'american dad S1-EP8',
    'american dad S1-EP9'
]

pattern = "S(\\d+)-EP(\\d+)"

def key(episode):
    regex_match = re.search(pattern, episode)
    return tuple(map(int, regex_match.groups()))

print(sorted(episodes, key=key))
```

Output:

```
['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `re` module to extract name, episode, season etc. The `key_function` will sort the list by `Name`, `Season`, `Episode`:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"(.*) S(\d+)-EP(\d+)")


def key_function(value):
    name, season, episode = pat.search(value).groups()
    return name, int(season), int(episode)


print(sorted(lst, key=key_function))
```

Prints:

```
[
    "american dad S1-EP1",
    "american dad S1-EP2",
    "american dad S1-EP3",
    "american dad S1-EP4",
    "american dad S1-EP5",
    "american dad S1-EP6",
    "american dad S1-EP7",
    "american dad S1-EP8",
    "american dad S1-EP9",
    "american dad S1-EP10",
    "american dad S1-EP11",
    "american dad S1-EP12",
    "american dad S1-EP13",
    "american dad S1-EP14",
    "american dad S1-EP15",
    "american dad S1-EP16",
    "american dad S1-EP17",
    "american dad S1-EP18",
    "american dad S1-EP19",
    "american dad S1-EP20",
    "american dad S1-EP21",
    "american dad S1-EP22",
    "american dad S1-EP23",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `sorted` function with a key:

```
list1 = ['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19',
        'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9']

def get_last_digits(s):
    last_digits = s[s.index("P") + 1:]
    return int(last_digits)

list1.sort(key=get_last_digits)
```

Note: This only works if all episodes are the same season.

Answer (score 0):

The big question here would be whether you need to sort decimals or not. Assuming that you only care about integers (e.g. that `12.6` would come before `12.56`), then you can convert the list of strings to a list of lists, where each item in the list is either a string or an integer, then sort that:

```py
import re

RE_NUM = re.compile(r'(\d+)|(\D+)')

def sort_mixed(strings):
    # sort list of strings with integers embedded in them
    split_strings = []
    for string in strings:
        split_string = [(int(i or 0), i or s) for i, s in RE_NUM.findall(string)]
        split_strings.append(split_string)
    return [''.join(s for _, s in v) for v in sorted(split_strings)]

# example usage
sort_mixed(['15.51', '12.9', '15.6.6', '15.6'])
# ['12.9', '15.6', '15.6.6', '15.51']
```

Note: Unlike other answers in this thread, the above works for any combination of integers and strings, including both no integers, no strings, or any number of integers more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the sorted key by `lambda`. (BTW, avoid to name a variable as `list` in python because it's a reserved word [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864221/is-the-list-of-python-reserved-words-and-builtins-available-in-a-library))

For more details about lambda, you can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)

**Example:**

```
l = ['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19', 'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9']
sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split("-EP")[1]))
print(sorted_l)
```

Or, python can sort one list based on values from another list (check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618515/sorting-list-based-on-values-from-another-list)). You can create a new list, which only contains ep number.

**Example:**

```
l = ['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19', 'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9']
ep_list = [int(x.split("-EP")[1]) for x in l]
sorted_l = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ep_list, l))]
print(sorted_l)
```

output:

```
['american dad S1-EP1', 'american dad S1-EP2', 'american dad S1-EP3', 'american dad S1-EP4', 'american dad S1-EP5', 'american dad S1-EP6', 'american dad S1-EP7', 'american dad S1-EP8', 'american dad S1-EP9', 'american dad S1-EP10', 'american dad S1-EP11', 'american dad S1-EP12', 'american dad S1-EP13', 'american dad S1-EP14', 'american dad S1-EP15', 'american dad S1-EP16', 'american dad S1-EP17', 'american dad S1-EP18', 'american dad S1-EP19', 'american dad S1-EP20', 'american dad S1-EP21', 'american dad S1-EP22', 'american dad S1-EP23']
```