# Python string behaviour shadowing builtin file object

Tags: python, built-in, shadowing

I'm having some trouble writing a script in Python 2.7 on Windows. In part of the script, I need to compose a windows file path from a directory and filename with extension. It works fine when I write it in as a string, but I get an error when I try to do it as a concatenate. I think it might have something to do with spaces in the paths.

Here is a code section that works

```
filepath = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files/122484.pdf")

print find_filename(filepath)
```

And here is the code section that doesn't work

```
directory_path = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files")

file = "122484.pdf"

filepath = os.path.join(directory_path, file)
print find_filename(filepath)
```

I'm having a really hard time seeing what the difference between these two would be. Here's the code in context of the entire script.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import os


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str

def find_filename(filepath):
    try:
        filenumberlocation = re.search('\d\d\d\d\d\d\.pdf',filepath, re.IGNORECASE)
        filenumber = filenumberlocation.group()[:6]
        print filepath
        pdfconverted = convert_pdf_to_txt(filepath)
        revlocation = re.search('REV #\n....',pdfconverted)
        rev = revlocation.group()[-4:]
        new_filename = filenumber + ' ' + rev + '.pdf'
        return new_filename
    except AttributeError:
        return os.path.basename(filepath)

def list_files(directory_path):
    filenames_list = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory_path):
        filenames_list.extend(filenames)    
    return filenames_list

directory_path = os.path.normpath("C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files")

file_list = list_files(directory_path)

for file in file_list:
    filepath = os.path.join(directory_path, file)
    os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(directory_path, find_filename(file)))
```

The error that I get says the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "revfind.txt", line 59, in <module>
        os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(directory_path, find_filename(file)))
    File "revfind.txt", line 34, in find_filename
        pdfconverted = convert_pdf_to_txt(filepath)
    File "revfind.txt", line 16, in convert_pdf_to_txt
        fp = file(path, 'rb')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

As you can probably tell, I'm very new at this, and would really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Wow... never seen someone name a *Python* file with a `.txt` extension before :)

Comment: Well don't assign `file` to a string if you want to use it to open a file later on. Or better use `open()` for opening files.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary is right, you assign `file` as a global variable in `for file in file_list:` statement. After that all calls of `file()` will try to make a call that string variable, not built in function. You may access build `file` via `__builtins__.file`, but it is very dirty.

Comment: Don't shadow the the builtin [**file object**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) ! Rename your variable from `file`. Don't ever call your list `list`, don't call your string `string`, don't call your dict `dict`, don't call your set `set`, don't call your operator `operator`... you can call your function `function` (in Python), but you still shouldn't.

Comment: ...don't call your object `object`, and don't call your type `type`, to flog the horse comprehensively. Please read questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595922/list-of-python-keywords

Comment: In honor of this I asked ["Weirdest obfuscated Python code which intentionally shadows builtins, to bizarre effect?"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47156/weirdest-obfuscated-python-code-which-intentionally-shadows-builtins-to-bizarre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that you are *shadowing* the `file` builtin - that's the effect of this line:

```
file = "122484.pdf"
```

From that point on, `file` is a string rather than the builtin function. The general advice for this problem is "don't do that" - ie, pick another name (calling it `filename` instead might be a good choice). However, in this case, the better advice would be to use the `open` function here, since `file` is a deprecated alias for it (which has been removed in Python 3). So, when you do this:

```
fp = file(path, 'rb')
```

do this instead:

```
fp = open(path, 'rb')
```

This *particular* use of a name shadowing a builtin happens to be safe and is probably unsurprising, but you should be careful of it in general.

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing the builtin [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects)

Don't do that. Call your variable `f`, `myfile`, `thefile` or whatever.

Don't shadow names of builtins. Don't ever call your list `list`, don't call your string `string`, don't call your dict `dict`, don't call your set `set`, don't call your operator `operator`... you can call your function `function` (in Python), but you still shouldn't.
...don't call your object `object`, and don't call your type `type`.

Answer (score -1):

The difference has to be in the string passed to find_filename, and it is different between the two versions.

With your first version, that works, the slashes in the directory are all forward slashes, including the one before the filename:

C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files/122484.pdf

On Windows, the os.path.join without a trailing slash will append a backslash before the filename, resulting in:

"C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files\122484.pdf

If you add a forward slash to the end of the directory name, the os.path.join will produce the same result as your example that worked.

Comment: Possibly true but not the problem here. `file` is being assigned to a string and overriding the builtin function

Comment: Windows correctly handles mixed slashes - `C:/Users/jpettit/documents/projects/vendor files script/test files\122484.pdf` is *unusual*, but is a valid path. Even if it wasn't, this isn't the main problem as it cannot possibly generate the particular error given in the question.