# Mergesort Python numerical ordering in a list

Tags: python, mergesort

I am trying to implement the mergesort algorithm in Python.  My input, file.txt, is of the form:

```
1
2
3
4
5
55
60
82
19
```

However, my output becomes (notice the second element of the list):

```
[['1'], ['19'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['55'], ['60'], ['82']]
```

Can someone please explain why this implementation of mergesort fails to place the 19 into its proper location in the Python list?

```
import csv

list = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')
    for line in lines:
        list.append(line)

def mergesort(list):
    mid = len(list)//2
    lft, rgt = list[:mid], list[mid:]
    if len(lft) > 1: lft = mergesort(lft)
    if len(rgt) > 1: rgt = mergesort(rgt)
    res = []
    while lft and rgt:
        if lft[-1] >=rgt[-1]:
            res.append(lft.pop())
        else:
            res.append(rgt.pop())
    res.reverse()
    return (lft or rgt) + res

print mergesort(list)
```

Comment: Avoid naming your variable using Python keyword, for example `list = []`

Comment: `list` is *not* a Python keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595922/list-of-python-keywords

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should explain what is happening:

```
matt$ python
>>> '19' < '2'
True
>>> int('19') < int('2')
False
```

When comparing strings, the string `'19'` is less than the string `'2'` because the character `'1'` comes before the character `'2'`.

If you convert the strings to numbers, the sorting should come out correctly.