# Test answer of the boolean 'true' explaination

Tags: python-2.7

[image]

Im very confused why the first 3 arnt all correct. As isn't true a keyword, it of course is a Boolean literal and is interchangeable with 1?

Comment: it's a literal not a keyword

Comment: What makes something a keyword? Believe i read in 3.0 was made into one, so i assume was due to 2.7.

Comment: Because they are actual values (1 and 0). Keywords are not.

Comment: oh okay, and since can be changed as well. thanks!

Comment: If this is Python 2.7, none of those are correct. It is not a keyword or a literal, and it is not the same as either 0 or 1. In Python 3, the first two are correct.

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `False` are not keywords, they are boolean values because they are associated with 1 and 0 respectively. For a complete list of keywords see [Is it possible to get a list of keywords in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python)

Comment: They're not literals either. You can assign `True = 12`, or even `import __builtin__; __builtin__.True = 12`, and change what `True` evaluates to, whereas you couldn't do that with a literal.

Comment: @user2357112 those updates you are referring to came about in Python 3.x.x I believe. In which case they are keywords, but the original question pertained to python 2.7.

Comment: I'm saying that in 2.7, they are neither literals nor keywords. The fact that they're not one doesn't make them the other.