# Random shuffle each 2 letters in a word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Its possible to shuffle a word each two characters in a randomic way?
Like `hello world` changed to `ehllo owlrd` or `hello wolrd` or `ehll owolrd`.

I cant get something like the following results: `olleh dlrow` and `lleho wodlr`

Comment: Sure. I imported the random library and tried to shuffle with `''.join...` (sorry, I'm in the phone, will edit with the right code when home)

Comment: How would you like to treat spaces?  Get rid of them and then re-insert before shuffling?

Comment: @BradSolomon in the third example output, it seems like the space was treated as just another character: `"ehll owolrd"`

Comment: You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: @boardrider i'm sorry? What this help me with my question? Brad and Juan got it and help me tho

Comment: It may help you in future interactions with SO, when good souls like @Brad et al. won't be there to bend the rules for you. You'll understand more once you read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

Break up the pairs of twos, sample, and recombine:

```
from random import sample

s = 'hello world'
twos = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)] # Step 1
twos = ''.join([''.join(sample(two, len(two))) for two in twos]) # Step 2

print(twos)
ehll oowrld
```

### Walkthrough

Step 1 uses list comprehension, basically a condensed for-loop.  Specifying
`range(0, len(s), 2)` iterates over an object with a step size of 2.  The best
way to easily visualize is to set `i` equal to its progressive values: 
`s[0:0+2]` will give you `'he'`, and so on.  The result of Step 1 is 
`['he', 'll', 'o ', 'wo', 'rl', 'd']`.

The inner part of Step 2 also uses list comprehension to iterate over each of
the pairs established in Step 1.  `for two in twos` says to perform the action
for each element in the list `twos` established in the previous step.  You could replace each instance of `two` with any word that you like, such as `pair` (just don't use a [keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python)).  Then using `''.join()` concatenates the broken-up strings back together.

Note: this treats spaces as characters to involve in the shuffling.

Comment: it worked like a charm, but, unfortunately, i didnt understand your code. I am trying to, but I am a newbie in python. Thanks tho

Comment: Updated with some annotation.

Comment: Thank you Brad. When I got it I understand how simple the code is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, put your string in some mutable data structure, like a `list`. Then a straightforward algorithm would be to iterate by two, starting at the second item, and randomly swap:

```
>>> def shuffle_by_two(word):
...     wordl = list(word)
...     for i in range(1, len(word), 2):
...         if random.randint(0, 1):
...             wordl[i-1], wordl[i] = wordl[i], wordl[i-1]
...     return ''.join(wordl)
...
```

So, for example:

```
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'hello wolrd'
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'hello wolrd'
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'ehllo owrld'
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'ehllo world'
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'hello owlrd'
>>> shuffle_by_two("hello world")
'ehll oowrld'
>>>
```