# Pass data value in python

Tags: python, pycharm

[python code line for get value from the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQqS2.png)

```
pass = form.getvalue('name',)
```

when i try to set form data value to this 'pass' variable it gives two errors near the equal mark.

1. End of statement expected.
2. Statement expected, found py:EQ

Why?

Comment: because `pass` is a keyword. don't use it as a variable.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. i'm just beginning my self study

Answer (score 1):

you're unlucky enough to have stumbled on a python keyword (the *null* statement that does nothing except make indentation happy).

hich is currently:

```
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif',
 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import',
 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try',
 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

(from [Is it possible to get a list of keywords in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642087/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-keywords-in-python))

As opposed to built-in functions like `sum` or `list`, keywords cannot be used / overridden without triggering strange syntax errors.

Comment: I didn't find any duplicate to this basic err, python :)) question so I answered as community wiki. If someone finds a proper duplicate feel free to suggest / close